# Unable to get alarms to work on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So I've been trying to get this to work for while, looked at a lot of questions and replies here, and copied some of the code; but it doesn't work for me.
I'm happy that the actual manipulation of the AlarmManager is right; but I think it's something to do with the way I'm setting up to use intents.
Here's the relevant part of the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <receiver android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <activity
    android:name="com.software.company.myapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>    
</application>
```

I believe that the action and category are both correct; but I'm not sure that the permission is required.

Then I set up the variables I'll need, here:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        intent=new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmService=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        MyAlarmReceiver alarmReceiver=new MyAlarmReceiver();
....
```

where MyAlarmReceiver is, for the moment:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{ 
    public void MyAlarmReceiver(){}
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.i("Log","Alarm went off");
    }
}
```

and the actual alarm setting is this

```
alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,lowest,alarmIntent);
```

....

```
}  // This marks the end of MainActivity
```

The code runs successfully, but never sees an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Strange to answer my own problem; but it might help someone else.
In my case, the above is all correct, except that MyAlarmReceiver can't be nested within the activity - it must be a separate class (in a separate file).
I'm also not using ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP any more, but RTC_WAKEUP.
If I do that, it works - not perfectly: since I need to display a screen and get some of the application data I'm starting the main activity with some extra data I can detect, which doesn't work if the application is still running; but is fine if it's not.
And here it is:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void AlarmReceiver(){}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
Intent i;

    i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.software.package");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setPackage(null);
    i.putExtra("is_alarm",true);
    context.startActivity(i);   
}
```

}

and in the main Activity, in onCreate:

```
        if(receivedIntent.getBooleanExtra("is_alarm",false)){ startAlarm(); }
```